# How to segregate these divs with 'position:absolute' into different groups?

Tags: css

Here is my html:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='text text-1'>1</div>
    <div class='alt-text alt-text-1'>A1</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='text text-2'>2</div>
    <div class='alt-text alt-text-2'>A2</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='text text-3'>3</div>
    <div class='alt-text alt-text-3'>A3</div>
</div>
```

In each row the `text` divs should be covered by `alt-text` divs. Here is an example of what I want to achieve visually:

```
A1
A2
A3
```

Here is my css:

```css
.row {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.alt-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

However this does not work correctly. All the divs lump together. All I see is

```
A3
```

(code: http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/zrMzbe)

How can I keep each pair of `text` and `alt-text` in their row?

Comment: Remove the background color from the `.alt-text` class. It's just covering the underlying text. Or am I not understanding?

Comment: You misunderstand the question

Comment: 1. Fix your closing divs. 2. Why are you using position absolute? If you don't give them a position (top, right, bottom, left) they are just going to the top left of the parent element

Comment: 1. Fixed that and it is not the cause of the issue 2. I want `alt-text` to cover `text`. Please reread the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this css answers your question:

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
}

.alt-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I am however concerned about your html as this feels like a hack. Also please keep accessibility in mind when creating your html.

Comment: heh.. same thing I was just 15 seconds later :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.text` class entirely from the CSS.

You don't need to posiiton `.text` because, by default, it at the top left of the container. You just need to position the `.alt-text` class:

[**Updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWQLPx)

```css
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.alt-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```